# PHP coding standards for user entered data

Tags: php

Recently we are facing lot of problems with user entered data

like

1. They are using different languages
2. entering special characters like " '

How to deal with all these, after one problem..we are facing another.

OR, are there any coding standard or advanced tutorials available?

Thanks

Comment: "Causing problems" how? Where? The first rule, regardless of language, is to never trust user input and to have a basic understanding of the concepts described in [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: using UTF-8 or UTF-16 should do the trick, don't validate text in English only [a-z] and make sure your database is setup to save foreign characters

Comment: Just one golden rule: *NEVER trust user input*

Comment: WOW, -6... great... people are ready to mark negative than answer a real world problem

Comment: Your question is simply too vague to be answerable. Define what problems you have exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally try to 'escape' all special characters when dealing with user supplied input.

If you find certain characters are causing havoc with your system then you can remove them like so:

```
<?php

$BadChars = array(
"'",    // Single quote - can harm SQL queries
"%",    // Percent sign - can harm SQL queries
"<",    // Less Than - can be used for XSS
">",    // Greater Then - can be used for XSS
";",    // Semicolon - can harm SQL queries
"£" 
);    

// $Input = $_GET['Name'];

$Input = "HELLO'%<;TEST";

foreach ( $BadChars as $Char )
{
    $Input = str_replace($Char, "", $Input);
}

print "Filtered Input: $Input";

?>
```

You can also escape data before it goes into a database using existing functions such as http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to pick these characters out of the data, you might want to consider Regular Expressions. Check out the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).